# JS how to make Chrome auto-fill inject values without user input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, autocomplete, webkit

I'm writing an auto login chrome extension.
To login to the website that I'm targeting you need to put:
Username, Password and student ID.
Since Chrome auto-complete save only the username and password I developed a small extension which inject the student ID and press the login button.

**I decided to let my extension handle only the student ID which isn't save automatically by chrome, and let the chrome browser keep the user and password safe. even that I keep everything at the local storage. and that there is no server side**

What I noticed is even that the autocomplete insert the values, 
and they are appearing on the screen, the user must press any keyboard/mouse button so the values will trigger the "change" event and the input will have the right value.

I'm trying to simulate it but sadly without any success, by invoking focus/select/change event.

my background.js:

```
var bgUserIDKey="OUAL_USER_ID"
var currentURL="";
var sendClick = "document.getElementsByTagName('input')[3].click();";
var triggerOnChange="$('#p_sisma').trigger('keydown');$('#p_user').trigger('keydown');";



function BackgroundLogin(){    
  if (currentURL.includes("sso.apps.openu.ac.il/SheiltaPortalLogin?"))
{
    this.SendScriptIntoActiveTab({code:"document.getElementById('p_mis_student').value="+GetUserID()+";"});
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      this.SendScriptIntoActiveTab({code:sendClick});
      this.SendScriptIntoActiveTab({code:this.triggerOnChange});

      this.SendScriptIntoActiveTab({code:"document.getElementById('p_mis_student').value="+GetUserID()+";"});
      BackgroundLogin();

    },350);
    console.log("OUAL Auto logged in.")
  }
}
```

it's injecting the id and as you can see it's trying to login every 350ms, 
when it's simulate the submit button the website does not recognize the username and password, and only work after any keyboard press or mouse click anyware at the page.

without any input from the user, the form can "see" only the student ID without the username & password even that they are inserted.
[image]
I tried multiple solutions that I found online but nothing seems to work.

Any Ideas?

Comment: focus the element and use document.execCommand with insertText parameter.

Comment: @wOxxOm are you talking about the studentID? since that's parameter is inserted just fine.
my problem is the username and password. 
I attached an image

Comment: I suggest using it instead of direct assignments to `value`.

Comment: @wOxxOm the problem is I don't keep at my extension the username and the password just the student id(even that I keep it only at the local storage) for security issues. I don't want my extension to handle sensitive data.

Comment: I don't see how these objections are related to my suggestion. Did you try it already? It should be as simple as code:"document.getElementById('p_mis_student').focus(); document.execCommand('insertText', false, '" + GetUserID()+"')"});

Comment: @wOxxOm 
first of all thank you for your time, yes I tried it but sadly still same result. :(